# Ubuntu disk start error "Starting track if upstart is running in a container [fail]"

Tags: 14.04, iso

I made a custum ubuntu distro. when I try to boot from it I get the error "Starting track if upstart is running in a container [fail]" and the screen gets stuck on the start screen. What can be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem seemed to be the instructions from the [LiveCDCustomization guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) that said to delete `initctl`:

> If you installed software, be sure to run ...
>
> `rm /sbin/initctl`
> `dpkg-divert --rename --remove /sbin/initctl`

The original `.iso` image *does* include `/sbin/initctl` in the squashfs filesystem. Adding that file back into my customized image solved the problem for me. I think the steps to remove `initctl` are only meant for 9.10, and are intended to undo the related steps from earlier in the guide:

> In 9.10, before installing or upgrading packages you need to run ...
>
> `dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl`
> `ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl`